# Searching database using seconds from Time

Tags: java, mysql, sql, date, datetime

In my database table I have a column with Time data, with a HH:MM:SS format, that contains the following type of data (the data type is time):

```
12:12:02
12:12:03
12:12:05...
12:13:01...
```

I need to create a query that takes the SS (second) data and searches and gets the data every minute from 01 to 59 sec. This is how I am thinking of doing this:

1. Time - Split into HH, MM, SS.
2. Using the SS (split) to search and get the data 00 to 59 seconds from the database
   2.2. While also getting the mm time and changing to +1 every time part 2. is done.
3. Then I will be able to add the results to an ArrayList with the full HH:MM:SS, not the split version.
4. Then I will be able to use search to get last MM (Minute) time and then start from that point in the next query at 1.

The main problem I think I will come across will be that when I split Time I would first have to convert it to String then using the timeSS to search the data type Time. A possible data mistype match error.

Another problem would be searching for the individual HH, MM, SS data in the database.

I would like some advice or help on the best way to do this.

Edit - 
Using MS Access
Data Type - Time

Comment: This question is not clear. Are you saying you want to query for records whose time value fall into a particular minute? Or you want records whose time value happens to be a particular second, each second of a certain minute (so 60 queries)? And is date involved? Are time zones involved? Databases typically store date-time value as the number of milliseconds since an [epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_%28reference_date%29), so it seems like you are making this unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: @BasilBourque I want to do the first, I want to query records whose time values fall within 1 minute, for every minute in my table, for example - first I get the records where the minute is 12 and then get the result set of the minute 13 and so on... Date and time zones are not involved. So a date-TIME value is in millisecond(s), so there is a method that can get the millisecond from a result set.

Comment: *Some* databases use milliseconds or nanoseconds in *some* of their date/time data types. For example Oracle apparently does a binary representation of date and time without time zone or offset in their [DATE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#i1847) without fractional seconds (clearly not a milliseconds count), and also has the common TIMESTAMP types which does include fractional seconds and is presumably a millisecond count but I cannot find documentation. Please rewrite your question to be more clear, and to say what database and data type you are using.

Comment: Based on the question text, your column design seems wrong.  Try using 3 columns; one for hour, one for minute, and one for second.  This way you can place an index on each column.

Comment: @DwB Yes I was thinking of actually splitting up the time when inserting into the database. I know that Access sucks just a little lazy to set up MySQL but I'm going to use MySQL.